# How to make a Random Name Exchange Picker with strict rules

Tags: c#

I am working on a small personal project that I can use for parties and gatherings where Exchanging of Gifts will benefit my application. Basically, my goal is to have an app that can generate a list of gift present giver-receiver from a pool of participants.

To better explain, say I have below table:

[image]

The rules would be as follows:

- Participants from Group X must not be assigned to a Participant from the same Group. (ex: Argus must not be assigned to Arian)
- The pairing must not go in two ways. (ex: if Bob was assigned to Clyde, Clyde shouldn't be assigned to Bob)

Therefore, given these parameters, the result would be like below in a real-world scenario:

[image]

I have had multiple iteration of codes in trying to achieve this, but none have been successful so far, I'm still working on several new approach, but suggestions and other's approach are more than welcome!

Below are my iterations:

`SessionMember` Class Model

```
public class SessionMember
{
    public int SessionMemberID { get; set; }
    public string ParticipantName { get; set; }
    public string FamilyGroupName { get; set; }
    public string ContactDetail { get; set; }
    public int ExchangeSessionMemberID { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExchangeDate { get; set; }
}
```

The list of members/participants are stored in a `List<SessionMember>()` variable named `MemberCollection`.

`Iteration A - Results in Infinite Loop`

```
{
    RestartPickSession:
    var sessionMemberCollection = new List<SessionMember>(MemberCollection);

    for (int i = 0; i < sessionMemberCollection.Count; i++)
    {
        var exchangeSessionMemberMatches = (from smc in sessionMemberCollection
                                            where smc.FamilyGroupName != sessionMemberCollection[i].FamilyGroupName &&
                                                  smc.ParticipantName != sessionMemberCollection[i].ParticipantName &&
                                                  smc.ExchangeSessionMemberID == 0
                                            select smc.SessionMemberID).ToList();

        if (exchangeSessionMemberMatches.Count == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Retrying...");
            goto RestartPickSession;
        }
        else
        {
            sessionMemberCollection[i].ExchangeSessionMemberID = exchangeSessionMemberMatches[new Random().Next(0, exchangeSessionMemberMatches.Count - 1)];
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Done...");
    goto End;
}
```

`Iteration B - Forever assigned a Match to a Participant`

```
{
    Restart:

    var sessionMemberCollection = new List<SessionMember>(MemberCollection);
    var exchangedMemberCollection = new List<SessionMember>();

    var noExchangePickCount = (from smc in sessionMemberCollection where smc.ExchangeSessionMemberID == 0 select smc).Count();

    while (noExchangePickCount != 0)
    {
        var sessionMember = sessionMemberCollection[new Random().Next(0, noExchangePickCount - 1)];

        var exchangeMemberMatches = (from smc in sessionMemberCollection
                                     where smc.FamilyGroupName != sessionMember.FamilyGroupName &&
                                           smc.ParticipantName != sessionMember.ParticipantName
                                     select smc).ToList();

        if (exchangeMemberMatches.Count == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Restarting...");

            goto Restart;
        }
        else
        {
            sessionMember.ExchangeSessionMemberID = exchangeMemberMatches[new Random().Next(0, exchangeMemberMatches.Count() - 1)].SessionMemberID;
        }
    }

    goto End;
}
```

`Iteration C - Stuck in "Restarting..."`

```
{
    Restart:

    var sessionMemberCollection = new List<SessionMember>(MemberCollection);
    var exchangedMemberCollection = new List<SessionMember>();

    while (sessionMemberCollection.Count != 0)
    {
        int i = new Random().Next(0, sessionMemberCollection.Count - 1);

        var sessionMember = sessionMemberCollection[i];

        var exchangeMemberPool = (from smc in sessionMemberCollection
                                  where smc.FamilyGroupName != sessionMember.FamilyGroupName &&
                                      smc.ParticipantName != sessionMember.ParticipantName
                                  select smc).ToList();

        if (exchangeMemberPool.Count == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Restarting...");
            goto Restart;
        }
        else
        {
            int j = new Random().Next(0, exchangeMemberPool.Count - 1);

            sessionMember.ExchangeSessionMemberID = exchangeMemberPool[j].SessionMemberID;

            Console.WriteLine($"{sessionMember.ParticipantName} -picked- {exchangeMemberPool[j].ParticipantName}");

            exchangedMemberCollection.Add(sessionMember);
            sessionMemberCollection.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Looking forward to everyone's idea, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code with a breakpoint. In Iteration A, the code always goes to "if (exchangeSessionMemberMatches.Count == 0)" and the count is always 0.

Perhaps you need to change the code so that it goes to the else statement at least once?

Answer (score 0):

After several more prototypes I finally came up with a working code. Sharing it with everyone just in case you guys need it to, you can play with it or improve upon it. but as for me, it works and that's what matters at the moment.

Restart:

```
IsExchangeProcessRunning = true;

var sessionMemberCollection = new List<SessionMember>(MemberCollection);
var exchangedMemberCollection = new List<SessionMember>();

var familyGroups = (from smc in sessionMemberCollection select smc.FamilyGroupName).Distinct();

// Loop through each group
foreach (string familyGroup in familyGroups)
{
    // Get Family Group Members
    var members = (from smc in sessionMemberCollection where smc.FamilyGroupName == familyGroup select smc);

    // Loop through each Family Group Members
    foreach (var member in members)
    {
        ExchangePickStatus = $"Assigning a match to {member.ParticipantName}...";

        Thread.Sleep(100);

        // Get Pool of potential exchange picks (excluding Picked Members, and members from the same Family Group)
        var exchangePool = (from smc in sessionMemberCollection
                            where smc.FamilyGroupName != familyGroup &&
                                 !smc.SessionMemberID.IsInList(exchangedMemberCollection.Select(x => x.ExchangeSessionMemberID))
                            select smc.SessionMemberID).ToList();

        if (exchangePool.Count == 0)
        {
            ExchangePickStatus = "Pool exhausted, restarting...";
            Console.WriteLine("Pool exhausted, restarting...");
            goto Restart;
        }

        // Get random index number from the pool of Exchange Members
        int i = new Random().Next(0, exchangePool.Count - 1);

        exchangedMemberCollection.Add(new SessionMember
        {
            SessionMemberID = member.SessionMemberID,
            ParticipantName = member.ParticipantName,
            FamilyGroupName = member.FamilyGroupName,
            ContactType = member.ContactType,
            ContactDetail = member.ContactDetail,
            ExchangeSessionMemberID = exchangePool[i],
            ExchangeDate = DateTime.Now
        });

        ExchangePickStatus = $"{member.ParticipantName} assigned a match...";
        Console.WriteLine($"[NEP] {member.ParticipantName} assigned a match...");
    }
}

// Check if there is a reverse pick
foreach (var exchangedMember in exchangedMemberCollection)
{
    bool isReversed = (from emc in exchangedMemberCollection
                       where emc.SessionMemberID == exchangedMember.ExchangeSessionMemberID &&
                             emc.ExchangeSessionMemberID == exchangedMember.SessionMemberID
                       select emc).Count() == 0 ? false : true;

    if (isReversed)
    {
        ExchangePickStatus = "Reverse match found, restarting...";
        goto Restart;
    }
}
```